# Access the ui element of another Qt Designer Form Class

Tags: qt, class, qt-designer

In my class I have an element of a class that was designed with QtDesigner.
It is a dialog an I use it like this:

```
int status = dialogA->exec();
```

but when I want to access the Designer Form in this dialog via

```
dialogA->ui->someelement
```

I get `invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Ui::DialogA'`.
Of course `ui` is normally private, but **I declared it to be public**.

So how can I access the elements in the ui element in the other class?

*(If this is too confusing I can try to expand to make it clear...)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the ui object is declared in the generated ui_*.h file.

**But** this is a very, very, very bad idea. Please do yourself a favor and define clean get/set methods in your dialog class to access the text properties of your ui elements (or whatever) - but no direct access to ui elements of separated classes. This will cause massive problems in future when you change the dialog class.

Comment: ...few days later. I'm convinced. Never do such a thing! *g*